# Why tables created in hibernate are deleted after stopping the server?

Tags: java, hibernate

I run my website and it generates the tables in the database. I even get to register in the database at your site and give a select shows that it was registered. But if I stop the server, and view tables in mysql, the table disappeared.

The persistence looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="nome">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>br.com.nome.model.Tabela</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="senha" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, was set up in the spring as drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the string "hbm2ddl.auto" in your entire source code and see if the value of that property is set programmatically to "create-drop".  That would result in the observed behavior.